# GTK3 Window Refresh

Tags: gtk3, gtk2

I have noticed that in GTK3 windows are redrawn when fully updated, e.g. when I resize Eclipse, it takes 1 second to redraw window, but when it is redrawn, it is in its final state, so GTK3 redraws only once.

With GTK2, when I resize window, it is redrawn instantly and then slowly updated.

The way GTK2 works is a lot better over VNC and NX.
Therefore I am looking for some ways of making GTK3 refreshing windows just like GTK2 does.

I could not find any configuration option so far nor anything in the API which could change that...